# Prove that the derivative is unique

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can someone maybe elaborate on what this question wants me to do exactly  and perhaps give me a hint?

Prove that $f:I\to \mathbb {R}$ has a derivative at $c\in I$ if and only if there exist a number 
$A\in \mathbb {R}$ and a function $\eta:I\to \mathbb {R}$ such that 
$f(x) - f(c) = A (x-c) + \eta(x)$ for every $x\in I$ and $\lim_{x\to c} \left(\frac{\eta(x)}{x-c}\right) =0$.
Show directly that when they exist, $A$ and $\eta$ are uniquely determined, thus $A = f'(c)$.

EDIT:
Assume that $A$ is not uniquely determined then $f^{'}(c)= A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ $f(x)-f(c)=A_1(x-c)+\eta_1(x)=A_2(x-c)+\eta_2(x)$ then 
$ A_1-A_2=\frac{\eta_2(x)-\eta_1(x)}{x-c}$.

Further $  A_1-A_2=\lim_{x \to c}\frac{\eta_2(x)-\eta_1(x)}{x-c}=0$( if it did not then $f^{'}(c)$ would not exist contradicting the question. thus $A_{1}=A_{2}$ Hence A must be uniquely determined. thus $\eta$ is also unique determined.

Comment: You can divide both sides with something that will give you an expression related to the derivative on the left (the assumption they gave, might give you a hint...)

Comment: Restated, this problem is asking you to show that if f has a derivative at c, then f can be approximated by a linear function near $c$: $f(x)=A(x-c)+f(c)+\eta(x)$. Think of $\eta(x)$ as the error term -- it goes to 0 very quickly near c. Then they want you to show that conversely, this also characterizes having a derivative, and the slope of this linear approximation is the same as the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $f(x)-f(c)=A_1(x-c)+\eta_1(x)=A_2(x-c)+\eta_2(x)$ then 
$ A_1-A_2=\frac{\eta_2(x)-\eta_1(x)}{x-c}$. Now take the limit as $x\to c$.

Comment: I actually understand that you've shown that A1=A2 im not sure what the proper assumption on A1 and A2 that showing they are same proves that each one is unique but ill probably figure it out eventually =)